# Unable to understand android location feature

Tags: android, locationmanager

In my app I need to determine user location. So I am using location manager. In my code, I first check for availability of network provider and GPS provider. I prefer networkprovider first, else I use GPS provider to get the location.

In an android device, there are three options available for location setting:
high accuracy(gps+wifi+mobile network)

battery saving(wifi+mobile network)

device only(GPS)

When within my house(WIFI on), I observe that first two options work but third one doesn't. So I ventured out of house(WIFI gone,no internet), and made observations again at a fixed point. There again, first two options worked but not the third.
Why is it so?GPS is supposed to work in open space.So I should get location for GPS too.

Then I got into a vehicle, and tested again. But now none of the options work.Even first two options stopped giving result. 
Why this behaviour? I expect all three options to work outdoor. But GPS never works, and first two work only when I am stationery. Does movement plays a role here?

I am not able to comprehend the overall behaviour.